# Create map from XYZ data stored in dataframe

Tags: r, geospatial

I have multiple XYZ files created by means of gdal2xyz.py script from GeoTIFF files (EPSG: 4326, WGS 84).

The purpose of exporting them to XYZ format, is to calculate maximum,minimum and average for each pixel.

Once accomplished, in my R! I have a data frame with three columns: two of them stores coordinates and the last one stores values.

An example of such data:

```
structure(list(X = c(16.91973877, 17.18004245, 17.44034612, 17.7006498, 17.96095347, 18.22125715), Y = c(54.35635376, 54.35635376, 54.35635376, 54.35635376, 54.35635376, 54.35635376), X2012.07.23 = c(2752L, 5422L, 7728L, 7178L, 8203L, 6909L)), .Names = c("X", "Y", "Mean"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Is it possible to draw such data directly as a 2D map within R! or do I need to export them to ASCII GRID or other raster format, read again and draw?
Most tutorials for GIS in R! which I found shows how to draw a vector or raster file. 
Ideally, I would like to display those values as pixels, but representation as a points (with clear information about value) is also okay for me.
In my example:
[image: Visualization of sample data in QGIS]

Comment: what do the `Mean`s represent in the figure, just text? `with(dd, {plot(X, Y, col = Mean); text(X, Y, Mean, pos = 1)})`

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Mean is a displayed text, as well as it's magnitude is related with each point color. Your example is okay for me, but is it possible to use different colors only (without text) and display legend on the bottom/top/anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to create a raster from your 'XYZ' data

```
library(raster)
r <- rasterFromXYZ(XYZ)
```

this is rather convoluted. You should use the original GeoTIFF files. For example

```
library(raster)
r <- raster('file.tif')
```

or, if there are multiple layers

```
b <- brick('file.tif')
```

and then, for example, to compute the mean for each cell

```
m <- mean(b)
```

Comment: Thank you. Guess that if I provide crs value in rasterFromXYZ command, I will be able to combine (create map) this raster with another GIS layers? Should be (?) something like this in my case: rasterFromXYZ(xyz, crs='+init=epsg:4326')